# Counting max contiguos non-empty cells per row in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a code in Google App Script to count the maximum number of contiguous non-empty cells per row. I already searched for the answer but I've found anything useful for this purpose.

Here you can find the example of my worksheet:

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGudp.png)

My goal is to write in column R the maximum consecutive working days for 2 weeks, in the picture I populated the R column with the results for every person.

There you can find the code I wrote (it is incomplete):

```js
function countingScript() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = sheet.getRange(3,5, lastRow-1, 14);
var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();  // Get array of values in the search Range
var counter = 0;
var counterArr = []; 
var maxArr = [];

// Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant

  for ( j = 5 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){    // j -> rows
    for ( i = 3; i < 17; i++){    // i -> columns
      if(rangeValues[j][i] != ""){
        counter = counter + 1;
          if(rangeValues[j][i] = ""){
              counterArr.push(counter);
            };        
          };
            var max = Math.max.apply(null, counterArr);  //find the maximum counter for every row
            
    };
/////// max array with the results of every row
    maxArr.push(max); // write this array in column R
  };
Logger.log(maxArr);  //there i shoould write the result of maxArr in column R
};
```

The idea of the script was create a counter that loops first every column to find a maximum value of contiguous non-empty cells and write it to an array (maxArr) and then resets the counter when passing to the next row.

Thank you very much,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can also use the following formula instead of the script:

```
=MAX(arrayformula(LEN(SPLIT(JOIN("",arrayformula(IF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(",",B5:O5),"[0-9 :-]+","1"),",",,FALSE)=1,"1"," ")))," "))))
```

[image: formula instead of the script]

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback and sorry for the late response! This is what I was looking for, the only "problem" is that the shift format has to be (for example) "06:00-14:30" without spaces and it does not work with spaces like "06:00 - 14:30". Do you know a way to avodi this? I've managed to create another support sheet with the MID function, but is there a smart way to do it directly with your formula?

Comment: I'm on the road right now, so I can't check, but it might be enough to add a space character to the regex: `"[0-9:- ]+"` or `"[0-9:-\s]+"`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working well and without additional sheets now!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that your problem is the counter not resetting to zero?
Try moving your 'var counter = 0;' inside your first array. This resets it to zero for every new row it loops through.

```
for ( j = 5 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){    // j -> rows
var counter = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, your hint is correct but I needed help also to complete the last part of the script and avoid "infinity" results.